# The macro `assert`, why doesn't it compile in the global scope?

Tags: c++, macros, assert

This snippet in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) doesn't compile. I understand the problem has to do with the fact that the `assert` macro is expanded in the global scope. That is, if we include the part of code below, starting with `assert(sieof(S)==8);` inside a function, like `main()` for example, the code will work.

```
#include <cassert>
struct S {
    char c;  // 1 byte value
             // 3 bytes padding
    float f; // 4 bytes value
    bool operator==(const S& arg) const { // value-based equality
        return c == arg.c && f == arg.f;
    }
};
assert(sizeof(S) == 8);
S s1 = {'a', 3.14};
S s2 = s1;
reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s1)[2] = 'b'; // change 2nd byte
assert(s1 == s2); // value did not change
```

But I want to understand why the code doesn't compile, as stated in the original code. For example in VS2013, the macro is defined as follows:

```
    #define assert(_Expression) (void)( (!!(_Expression)) ||
             (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#_Expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), __LINE__), 0) )
```

and the compiler complains with the following error message:

```
error C2062: type 'void' unexpected
```

The obvious question is: why is the `void` accepted inside `main` but not in the global scope?

See the error messages in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/259ea5dc70219985).

Comment: Those `assert` statements are runnable logic, put them in main or some function that is called: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80b9fb6afdf45e9b
Creation of  `s1` and `s2` is okay; they are file-level variables that will get initialized before main.

Comment: Remove the `assert` and you'll *still* get an error. You can't have `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s1)[2] = 'b'; // change 2nd byte` outside of a function either. The problem really isn't with `assert` at all.

Comment: @hvd But both compilers complain about the `assert` macro expansion

Comment: Aside: you can use static_assert in global scope and it would work for what you're trying to do here (i.e. assertions about things that can be determined at compile time such as sizeof).

Comment: @François-MarieArouet Sorry for not being clear. I meant the problem isn't specific to `assert`. You have the problem with *any* statement you put outside of a function. It just happens that `assert` is used in the first of your global statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global scope can only contain declarations. The assert macro expands to an expression statement, which cannot appear at global scope.

Comment: AFAICT, a function can be called in global scope. For example, this is a valid code: `int f() { return 5; } int a = f();`

Comment: @François-MarieArouet: How do you mean?

Comment: @DevSolar See the example I gave above.

Comment: @françois-marie: that's a declaration with an initializer, not an expression statement.

Comment: @François-MarieArouet Global objects can be initialized with a function in the global scope, but you can't run arbitrary code in the global scope. Why? Well how would the compiler know when to run the code? When you're defining a global object, you know the code runs when the object is initialized

Answer (score 2):

The `assert()` macro is a *run-time* assertion. It resolves to code, not a variable declaration / definition, and as such is not permitted at global scope.

The code after the `struct` definition is supposed to be inside some surrounding function; as-is it's more like pseudo-code to reinforce the point the surrounding text is making.

They just didn't bother with actually putting an `int main()` in the example at the appropriate place. Notice that there is no "run this code" button either -- that snippet is not *supposed* to be compiled as-is.

Answer (score 1):

assert() must in function like:

```
#include <cassert>
struct S {
    char c;  // 1 byte value
             // 3 bytes padding
    float f; // 4 bytes value
    bool operator==(const S& arg) const { // value-based equality
        return c == arg.c && f == arg.f;
    }
};
int main(){
    assert(sizeof(S) == 8);
    S s1 = {'a', 3.14};
    S s2 = s1;
    reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s1)[2] = 'b'; // change 2nd byte
    assert(s1 == s2); // value did not change
    return 0;
}
```